# In WPF, how to implement a file upload control (textbox and a button to browse file)?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, file-upload

I have a WPF,MVVM application.

I need the functionality same as "File Upload" control in asp.net.

Can somebody tell me how to implement that ?

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Width="150"></TextBox>
                <Button Width="50" Content="Browse"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

I have this xaml...but how to have that "browse window" when you click button ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use OpenFileDialog class to get a file choose dialog

```cs
OpenFileDialog fileDialog= new OpenFileDialog(); 
fileDialog.DefaultExt = ".txt"; // Required file extension 
fileDialog.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Optional file extensions

fileDialog.ShowDialog();
```

To read the content : You will get the filename from the OpenFileDialog and use that to do what IO operation on it.

```cs
if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileDialog.FileName);
     MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
     sr.Close();
}
```

Comment: `DialogResult.OK` doesn't exist, but I had it working with `bool? res = fileDialog.ShowDialog(); if(res.HasValue && res.Value) { ... }`

Comment: Note DialogResult.OK does exist if you are using System.Windows.Forms, which you can use but since this is WPF you would typically use Microsoft.Win32.

Answer (score 2):

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <TextBox Width="150"></TextBox>
     <Button Width="50" Content="Browse" Command="{Binding Path=CommandInViewModel}"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Declare a command in your view model and bind it in the view as I have done inside button. Now you will get control in the code once user will click the button. In that code create a window and launch it. Once user will close the window, read the contents and do whatever you want.