# How to add file path to custom control through [...] button of properties in design time in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf-controls, custom-controls, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to develop a wpf custom control component, where in i need to browse files from my local machine through property and need to select the file at design time. To do this we would need a button (...) and textbox to to hold the file path. File browsing and selection is done at design time and in run time the file should be displayed on the WPF form. I am able to achieve this Winforms (using UItype Editor ) however i am not able to do this in WPF as there is UItypeeditor is not available in wpf. 
I   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lam5a.png attached One Sample Property Image, Expected output in design time of Custom control properties for your quick reference.

I am a new bee in  WPF, request you to help with a sample code or link.
Thank you for helping me in Advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Here, it is always important to include code. Edit your question and add the code you are having issues with. Do not post everything. just the part you have issues with and enough for us to reproduce the situation.

Comment: I want File Browse through Property in Wpf Custom Control, i am very new to Coding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677082/c-sharp-wpf-property-grid-file-browser

Comment: i followed above link but i am not getting three dots button in properties , In windows and Web application i used UIType Editor There i got in Wpf i am not able to do Can you please help me.

Comment: Consider this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876833/in-wpf-how-to-implement-a-file-upload-control-textbox-and-a-button-to-browse-f

Comment: In Windows and web i used this line of code before Properties and i implement DailogBoxEditorMachine class that extends to UItypeEditor class.[Editor(typeof(DailogBoxEditorMachine), typeof(UITypeEditor))]

Comment: Hi @mw509 thanks for your response I want File Browse through Properties of Custom Properties.I gone through that link.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out might help you [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/38739b25-34f6-4896-bd2f-f9bdb58fab40/image-user-control-with-filepicker-option-inside-the-propertygrid-control?forum=wpf)..

Comment: Hi @RN thanks for your reply  i tried that link but i am not getting Design time That Select button.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please have a look at this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/xaml-designer-extensibility/tree/master/samples/CustomControlLibrary.WpfCore). it has a sample project with implementation.